# Use custom account instead of service account in Google API

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, google-drive-api

I am trying to connect to Google Drive from my App Engine code. But it requires Client code. Google App engine generates Client code (P12 key) only for the service account. But I want it for a technical user we have created.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the "technical user" you are referring to is a @gmail account, then your only option is to do the OAUTH dance once to obtain a oauth token and refresh token. You have to create a "Client ID for web application" to do this. Once you have the auth and refresh token, you can connect as your "technical user" to Google drive.

If the "technical user" you are referring to is a Google Apps account, then you can authorize the consumer key/secret related to the service account in the Google Apps control panel with the required Drive scopes. You will have to indicate  in the API call what user (i.e. the technical user) you want to impersonate when you connect to Google Drive.

Comment: If I use service account to create a spreadsheet in drive, how can I view the spreadsheets under that account? I mean in the web, since I don't have a password for the service account.

Comment: if you use a service account to create a spreadsheet, you will always do this on behalf of a real account (i.e. the technical user) onto whose drive the file is created.

Comment: Thanks koma. 
But would the service account have access to the sheet programatically?

Comment: @koma can please explain more about the second option.